# Newton's Cradle doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws

I'm trying to learn physics, and I have a question regarding Newton's Cradle.

I learned that momentum is conserved on a Newton's Cradle, and that momentum conservation is only for closed systems (no interaction with the external environment).

So, how Newton's Cradle can Conserve Momentum if we have the action of gravity on this, in addition, in each cycle we have an instant in which the velocity is null (and consequently the moment) for the whole system (when the sphere(s) reaches the highest point) so that the moment is not conserved.

Maybe I did not get it right, but when we speak conservation of momentum in Newton's Cradle, we are restricting to the moments in which the spheres collide?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Momentum is conserved in the absence of a net external force.**

Also momentum and force are vectors so we can analyse the motion in the line passing through the center of all the spheres (x-axis) and the line perpendicular to this (y-axis). 
There is no external force along the x-axis so momentum along x-axis is conserved. However as you correctly pointed out, force of gravity exists in the y direction and hence momentum is not conserved along y-direction.

The word external here is very important, because if you think about it, the electromagnetic force is responsible for the collision between the balls, however this is an internal force and hence if you are talking about the momentum of the system, this force can be ignored.

Comment: The whole idea of using Newton's cradle to study the conservation of linear momentum is at best confusing.
- The system is ill defined.
 Each ball has a rotational motion and therefore the conservation of angular momentum is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is correct. Only when the balls move horizontally their momentum is conserved. When a ball swings up its momentum is transferred is very nearly completely transferred to Earth and everything on it.